# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webpackHotUpdate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting this error when the browser hits the following line in the "webpackified" `app.js` file:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    function hotDisposeChunk(chunkId) {
/******/        delete installedChunks[chunkId];
/******/    }
/******/    var parentHotUpdateCallback = this["webpackHotUpdate"];
```

In the last line of this snippet, `this` is undefined.

Despite this error, the app seems to be running just fine.

I'm not sure what parts of my `webpack.config.js` file are most relevant, but here are some possibly relevant snippets:

#### webpack.config.js

```
const HotModuleReplcement = new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin();

...

module.exports = {

  ...

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    port: 8000,
    open: true,
    proxy: [{
      context: ['/assets', '/api'],
      target: 'http://localhost:4000',
      secure: false
    }]
  },
  plugins: [HotModuleReplcement, HtmlWebpack]
};
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

The core issue is that `"this"` should be `"self"` for webpages (as opposed to node).

The webpack.config.js should not be:

```json
output: {
    path: 'dist',
      filename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: '/',
      globalObject: 'this' // do no do "this"
  },
```

but should be more like this:

```json
output: {
    path: 'dist',
      filename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: '/',
      globalObject: 'self'
  },
```

[More from webpack.js.org](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject)